# javascript: assign function parameter if functioncall is a string?

Tags: javascript, api, function

Following example - the YoutubePlayer API

```
videoID.addEventListener('onStateChange', 'foo');
```

In the documentation they say, video.addEventListener(string: event, string: function).
That means the first parameter is the event (in my case onStateChange) and the second parameter is the function that is getting called when the even is triggered.

This youtube sample is just a good example, I've alredy had this question a few times before.
If the function to call is passed as a string, is there any chance to assign a a parameter to that function?

Imagine the function I want to call looks like this.

```
function foo(something) {
   console.log(something).
}
```

It's obviously not possible to add a parameter to the function call is it? Like…

```
videoID.addEventListener('onStateChange', 'foo(videoID)');
```

Thank you for your information and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
videoID.addEventListener('onStateChange', function()
{
    foo(videoID);
});
```

...if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: that is exactly what i'm looking for! it just doesn't seem to work! At least not with my youtube example!

Comment: Maybe give this a whirl:  `player.addEventListener("onStateChange", "foo");
}

function foo(newState) {
   alert("state: " + newState);
}`

Comment: does end in } unexpected token error! here is my testexample: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9Zvd/4/

Comment: I looked at your sample, what are you hoping to pass into there?  You could set a global variable and use that?

Comment: actually i want to pass along the player itself. ytplayer is changed dynamically, so i have multiple ytplayer's like ytplayer_1, ytplayer_2, etc. Every of those ytplayer's has this eventListener applied and listenes to the onStateChangeEvent. In my foo() function I want to be able to know which of the multiple ytplayer's triggered the event. http://jsfiddle.net/Z9Zvd/8/